# Precalc coursework - Is this an error?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am enrolled in a precalc math course at a university studying online. I haven't studied math in over 35 years so I'm a bit rusty. Why would my online math coursework have errors? I end up torn between feeling like I must just not understand something and certainty that there is an error in my professor's notes. I turn to you for confirmation and hopefully confidence.

I attach an image of the professor's solution, please could you confirm for me whether my belief that she is missing an X factor in her work and she then continues solving the equation incorrectly. Who is right?
[image: I am too new to embed images]

Comment: You are right. There is a missing $x.$ The final result should be $\dfrac{x+4}{2x^2}.$

Comment: My solution is x plus 4 over 2x squared.

Comment: Again, you are right.

Comment: @mfl I think you should post your answer as an answer.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @CiaPan I have follow your suggestion.

Comment: As for the "why": Professors are human.  They make mistakes.  Hopefully not too often, but it happens.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, learning this content is very important to me. The "why" leaked out because this is the fifth error and I am only on page 11. Her teaching is excellent, yet her online materials need review. It's making it quite a bit harder to learn.

Comment: As for 'who is NOT right' you could just plug $x=2$ and verify if the equalities hold – and which one does not.

Comment: Professors make way too much money for that kind of sloppiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. There is a missing $x.$ The final result should be $\dfrac{x+4}{2x^2}.$ Note that

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{x+3}\left(\frac{x+7}{2x}+\frac{6}{x^2}\right)& = \frac{1}{x+3}\left(\frac{(x+7)\cdot x}{2x\cdot x}+\frac{6\cdot 2}{x^2\cdot 2}\right)\\ &= \frac{1}{x+3}\left(\frac{x^2+7 x}{2x^2}+\frac{12}{2x^2}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{x+3}\frac{x^2+7 x+12}{2x^2} \\ &= \frac{x^2+7 x+12}{2x^2(x+3)}  \\ &= \frac{(x+4)(x+3)}{2x^2(x+3)}\\ &= \frac{x+4}{2x^2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: You may also indicate that $x^2+7x+12=(x+3)(x+4)$ which would make the last step obvious.

Comment: @CiaPan Thank very much for your comments, that help to improve the solution.